# how do you access mysql(linux) witihn the LAN network?

Tags: mysql, authentication

we have a linux box with mysql 5.2 installed.
I made sure it's running and double checked the port 3306 and it's open through (netstat -tulpn) but I can't in anyway access it on the network.
I checked with ping and all hosts are properly responding.

I try to access with a command like:

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.32 -u root -p
```

---

and it says `"unknown mysql host '...":`

what am I missing here?
it's mysql 5.2 running on CentOS

Comment: Check are you able to access 192.168.1.32?

Comment: Not a vote-to-close, but have you considered checking with [The Unix/Linux Stack Exchange site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)? ...okay, I'm sorry. Somehow I managed to vote-to-close as 'off-topic', if this question *gets* closed please notify me (with an '@David Thomas' message) and I'll vote to reopen. I certainly **don't** think it's a valid Serverfault question, as the other close-voter suggest. Again: I'm sorry, clicked in the wrong place... =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this -

1. Check if your host (192.168.1.32) is up. `ping 192.168.1.32`
2. If yes, then login to that machine & check if `mysqld` is running. `service mysqld status` (for Fedora) or `service mysql status` (for ubuntu)
3. If mysql is running, then login & see if appropriate permissions have been given to that machine, that database & that user. You can do this by logging into mysql as root & running this sql - `GRANT ALL ON <database_name>.* TO '<user>'@'192.168.1.32' IDENTIFIED BY "<password";`

Answer (score 0):

Is the mySQL server configured to only accept connections from localhost?